# Twitter authentication with angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter, oauth

I am getting the below error when I am trying to use the authentication process with twitter api. Can you please help. The link to my project on plunk is http://plnkr.co/edit/BcA0w5OpHjchJzjgipUO?p=preview

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token. Response for preflight is invalid (redirect)
```